# How to open a file in vscode from browser?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want my webapp to be able to open a given file in VS code. For example, when I click a button on my webapp, a file say, `C:\Users\...\myProject\index.html` is opened, if `myProject` is already opened it should navigate to `index.html`

I know its a peculiar use case but I want to know if its possible in vscode.

Its also completely fine if it requires using browser or vscode extension.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
vscode://file/{full path to project}/
```

Thanks to fbg13 for providing [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls)

Comment: In case vscode says _Unable to open 'index.php': resource is not available._, it's because of a bug reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/69998).

Answer (score 6):

It is possible if you add this link:

```
vscode://file/{fullpath}:{numrow}
```

### Example for Symfony 5.3 and higher

For example in **Symfony** to use the link that appears in the debug bar of the controller used you can do it as described in the examples. You have to edit your project config.

Only for **VS Code**:

*config\packages\framework.yaml*

```yaml
framework:
    ide: 'vscode://file/%%f:%%l'
```

For any editor through **env**:

*config\packages\framework.yaml*

```yaml
framework:
    ide: '%env(resolve:CODE_EDITOR)%'
```

And don't forget to add value for `CODE_EDITOR` into *.env* or *.env.local*.

#### Local

This is an example for local projects.

*.env* or *.env.local*:

```
CODE_EDITOR=vscode
# or
CODE_EDITOR=vscode://file/%%f:%%l
```

#### Docker

If you use **Docker** or trying to open a file from remote server, you may use this example.

*.env* or *.env.local*:

```
# Template
CODE_EDITOR=vscode://file/%%f:%%l&/PATH/TO/YOUR/SERVER/APP>/PATH/TO/YOUR/LOCAL/APP
# Real paths
CODE_EDITOR=vscode://file/%%f:%%l&/app/>/home/user/projects/symfony_project/
```

For more details see these pages:

- [Symfony Framework Configuration Reference - ide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ide)
- [Opening VS Code with URLs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls)

Answer (score 5):

It is possible if you are using Firefox:

- Open the `about:config` page.
- Set the `view_source.editor.external` to `true`.
- Set the `view_source.editor.path` to the VSCode's executable absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [vscode-handler](https://github.com/shengyou/vscode-handler) to open files like this

```
vscode://open?url=file://%file&line=%line
```